# Date is my index, need to fill na values to the index by filling the missing sequence of indexes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, indexing, time-series

this is my data set

```
RECEIPT_MONTH_YEAR   RECEIPT_MONTH
2014-01-01             1
2014-02-01             2
2014-03-01             3
2014-04-01             4
2014-05-01             5
2014-06-01             6
2014-07-01             7
2014-08-01             8
2014-09-01             9
2014-10-01             10
2014-11-01             11
2015-08-01             8
2015-09-01             9
2015-10-01             10
2015-11-01             11
2015-12-01             12
```

I had set the 'RECEIPT_MONTH_YEAR' as index I need to fill the missing dates 
and fill na values in the remaining variables

need out like

```
RECEIPT_MONTH_YEAR   RECEIPT_MONTH
2014-01-01             1
2014-02-01             2
2014-03-01             3
2014-04-01             4
2014-05-01             5
2014-06-01             6
2014-07-01             7
2014-08-01             8
2014-09-01             9
2014-10-01             10
2014-11-01             11
2014-12-01             NA
2015-01-01             NA
2015-02-01             NA
2015-03-01             NA
2015-04-01             NA
2015-05-01             NA
2015-06-01             NA
2015-07-01             NA
2015-08-01             8
2015-09-01             9
2015-10-01             10
2015-11-01             11
2015-12-01             12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `MS` in `asfreq`

```
df.set_index('RECEIPT_MONTH_YEAR').asfreq('MS').reset_index()
Out[62]: 
   RECEIPT_MONTH_YEAR  RECEIPT_MONTH
0          2014-01-01            1.0
1          2014-02-01            2.0
2          2014-03-01            3.0
3          2014-04-01            4.0
4          2014-05-01            5.0
5          2014-06-01            6.0
6          2014-07-01            7.0
7          2014-08-01            8.0
8          2014-09-01            9.0
9          2014-10-01           10.0
10         2014-11-01           11.0
11         2014-12-01            NaN
12         2015-01-01            NaN
13         2015-02-01            NaN
14         2015-03-01            NaN
15         2015-04-01            NaN
16         2015-05-01            NaN
17         2015-06-01            NaN
18         2015-07-01            NaN
19         2015-08-01            8.0
20         2015-09-01            9.0
21         2015-10-01           10.0
22         2015-11-01           11.0
23         2015-12-01           12.0
```

Update

```
s=df.set_index('RECEIPT_MONTH_YEAR').asfreq('MS').reset_index()
s['RECEIPT_MONTH']=s['RECEIPT_MONTH_YEAR'].dt.month
```

Comment: thank you so much its working, but now I want the value of the month in RECEIPT_MONTH column

Comment: thank you so much it works, Please look at the question i have updated, im having variable as NET_SALES, i need to fill the nan values with predicted by forecasting it. please help me out with ideas or codes

Comment: this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151197/need-to-fill-the-na-values-with-the-past-three-values-before-na-values-in-python