# need to fill the NA values with the past three values before na values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series, forecasting, fillna

need to fill the NA values with the past three values mean of that NA

this is my dataset

RECEIPT_MONTH_YEAR  NET_SALES

0      2014-01-01   818817.20

1      2014-02-01   362377.20

2      2014-03-01   374644.60

3      2014-04-01   NA

4      2014-05-01   NA

5      2014-06-01   NA

6      2014-07-01   NA

7      2014-08-01   46382.50

8      2014-09-01   55933.70

9      2014-10-01   292303.40

10     2014-10-01   382928.60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this dataset a .csv file or a dataframe. This NA is a 'NaN' or a string ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv('your dataset',sep=' ')
df.replace('NA',np.nan)
df.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
```

you mention something about mean of 3 values..the above simply forward fills the last observation before the NaNs begin. This is often a good way for forecasting (better than taking means in certain cases, if persistence is important)

```
 ind = df['NET_SALES'].index[df['NET_SALES'].apply(np.isnan)]
 Meanof3 = df.iloc[ind[0]-3:ind[0]].mean(axis=1,skipna=True)
 df.replace('NA',Meanof3)
```

Maybe the answer can be generalised and improved if more info about the dataset is known - like if you always want to take the mean of last 3 measurements before any NA. The above will allow you to check the indices that are NaNs and then take mean of 3 before, while ignoring any NaNs

Answer (score 0):

This is simple but it is working

```
df_data.fillna(0,inplace=True)
for i in range(0,len(df_data)):
if df_data['NET_SALES'][i]== 0.00:
    condtn = df_data['NET_SALES'][i-1]+df_data['NET_SALES'][i-2]+df_data['NET_SALES'][i-3]
    df_data['NET_SALES'][i]=condtn/3
```

Comment: this answer is very specific, and inefficient to run a loop when you are using dataframes,. if you dont want to use a loop.. It would be better to do,   `df_data['NET_SALES'][i] = df_data['NET_SALES'].iloc[i-3:i].mean(skipna=True)` where `i` is the list of indexes which are NA. the answer below does the same without running a loop

Answer (score 0):

You could use fillna (assuming that your NA is already np.nan) and rolling mean:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([818817.2,362377.2,374644.6,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,46382.5,55933.7,292303.4,382928.6], columns=["NET_SALES"])

df["NET_SALES"] = df["NET_SALES"].fillna(df["NET_SALES"].shift(1).rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean())
```

Out:

```
NET_SALES
0   818817.2
1   362377.2
2   374644.6
3   518613.0
4   368510.9
5   374644.6
6   NaN
7   46382.5
8   55933.7
9   292303.4
10  382928.6
```

If you want to include the imputed values I guess you'll need to use a loop.